# Query builder for Google Firebase FileStore

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Mongodatbase, we have a builder to generate the filter definition like below

```
*var filter = Builders<Setting>.Filter
                .Where(x => x.DocumentType.Equals(nameof(Setting))
                && x.Code.Equals(code)
                && x.PartationKey.Equals(partationKey));*
```

Like above, do we have any query builder in Firebase Filestore?

Comment: I think you mean to say "Firestore" and not "Filestore"? They are different products.

Answer (score 2):

Each language supported by Firestore has its own way of building queries.  You didn't say, but it looks like you might be using C# in your example.  There is, in fact, ways to build filtered queries with the provided [dotnet library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/firestore/v1).  I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#c) for examples.